# Am I a golfy array?

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, array, decision-problem

### Definition and Rules

A *golfy array* is an array of integers, where each element is *higher than or equal to* the arithmetic mean of all the previous elements. Your task is to determine whether an array of positive integers given as input is golfy or not.

- You do not need to handle the empty list.
- [Default loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).
- [Standard Input and Output methods apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- You can choose any two distinct non-empty values. They **must** be consistent, and must comply with all other [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem) rules. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in each language wins!

### Test Cases & Example

For example the following array:

```
[1, 4, 3, 8, 6]
```

Is a golfy array, because each term is higher than the arithmetic mean of those preceding it. Let's work it out step-by-step:

```
Number -> Preceding elements -> Average -> Follows the rule?

1      -> []                 -> 0.0     -> 1 ≥ 0.0   (True)
4      -> [1]                -> 1.0     -> 4 ≥ 1.0   (True)
3      -> [1, 4]             -> 2.5     -> 3 ≥ 2.5   (True)
8      -> [1, 4, 3]          -> 2.(6)   -> 8 ≥ 2.(6) (True)
6      -> [1, 4, 3, 8]       -> 4.0     -> 6 ≥ 4.0   (True)
```

All the elements respect the condition, thus this is a golfy array. Note that for the purpose of this challenge, we will assume that the average of an empty list (`[]`) is `0`.

More test cases:

```
Input -> Output

[3]                 -> True
[2, 12]             -> True
[1, 4, 3, 8, 6]     -> True
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]     -> True
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]     -> True
[3, 2]              -> False
[4, 5, 6, 4]        -> False
[4, 2, 1, 5, 7]     -> False
[45, 45, 46, 43]    -> False
[32, 9, 15, 19, 10] -> False
```

---

**Note that this is *[Puzzle 1](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/CodeGolf-Hackathon/blob/master/Puzzle%201/Puzzle%201.md)* from *[CodeGolf-Hackathon](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/CodeGolf-Hackathon)* and is also posted on [Anarchy Golf](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Golfy+ARrays) (that one is broken) - *[Reposted](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Golfy+Arrays+with+test+cases)* by [histocrat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6828/histocrat), but I am the original author on both sites, and thus allowed to repost them here.**

Comment: Is the input always a list of positive integers?

Comment: @KellyLowder Yes.

Comment: It's a fun problem, I was thinking of reposting it on Anarchy Golf with more test cases but thought you might be working on that.

Comment: @histocrat Go ahead and repost it on Anarchy Golf, I should have thought about the things that could be exploited first. I am rather glad you find it interesting (Btw please ping me here and give a link if you repost it).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Golfy+Arrays+with+test+cases

Comment: Hmm, having 0 as the average of an empty sub-list (to handle the first element) sounds strange. I guess using "all elements after the first" in the first sentence would be a better wording.

Comment: Is there a test case that works if you compare current term against average of previous terms, but *doesn't* if you compare current term against average of terms up to (and including) that term? My solution does the latter, (but|and) passes all test cases...

Comment: @histocrat Ok, thanks for letting me know you reposted it! (Heh, now I can compete too :P)

Comment: @streetster Those are equivalent. Sum/i > x is the same as Sum > xi is the same as Sum+x > x(i+1) is the same as (Sum+x)/(i+1) > x.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
def g(a):sum(a)>len(a)*a.pop()or g(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdHPa8IwFAfwe/@Kh6dGgtjWuVnobhsMxk7eJIduPl2hS8JLCvrXdy8pqBM7Q8I7vE@/@VF79N9G532/xR3s01qUrvvh8tyi5jKtZ9bYVBiKzah26bsoEwBPxxIIfUcaPo1p0z03BDfw8IXWw5ve4uGFyNCJranDJKmdQ/KcsykUXA0BVTWws8olZLm6pzIJCwmFhCcJS/WPyqNi@zCqlhxxmqOKU/4ea1CvdesuWdgpJi3UHRYuGvGjGmfcjisExve7yQrOWnEcyyzUubpglhrtYfJhYPigMRow/Cg3m/S/)

Outputs via exit code: crashes (exit code 1) for golfy arrays, just exits with exit code 0 for non-golfy arrays. ovs and Jonathan Frech saved 3 bytes.

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda a:a and sum(a)<=len(a)*a.pop()*f(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdBND4IgGAfwe5/imSd1zCWavSyuHTt1axxo6nJTcKCHPr094FbWMhnsGePHn5f20d2VpMNQslo0t1yAOOCQOZi@8UVwZHUhsYYialXrB2GJk0EYU@gOSv@acPhqATAGF90Xq7eiBGLKl1RMICWQENgRyPgfRZ1Cu5lVGUa8@qzClM9rjeokajNl9iSXlPIFZh/q8JbPM1x2wwa6//vJEszaYxzK2NY1n7BWV7ID76xg3FApCYXWSpvIG54)

A more traditional variant, which returns `True` for golfy arrays, else `False`. Jonathan Frech saved 2 bytes.

Comment: I think `a==[]or` can be `a and`.

Comment: That’s actually clever — it comes out to `sum(a)<=len(a)*a.pop()*[]` for the base case, which is always true as `int < list`!

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##hdFBS8MwFAfwez/FY6dGwljbOV2h3hSE4cmb5BDt2xx0SXhJYfv09SUFN8W6kPDa5td/2sSdwqc15TDsmk4f3lsNuvb9IdfioUPD5UbPnXW5sAQ7vh1a3MI234g6Awh0igV4ZiPSBWHoycCT7jzyAzx@oAvwbFo8PhJZqi/VK/WYZdp7pMCZb5WCX01A04zsrEoJRamuqULCUkIl4V7CSv2jyqTY3k6qFUd890nFKT8/a1TjVpxZXCklLdUVFn804Ts1zXg6jRiY9u9PVnHWmuNYFrEu1AVztDcBZi8Wxhf21gDGw/Lz2fAF) as a function which crashes for truthy inputs.

Comment: @ovs [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##hdHPa8IwFAfwe/@Kh6dGgtjWuVnobhsMxk7eJIduPl2hS8JLCvrXdy8pqBM7Q8I7vE@/@VF79N9G532/xR3s01qUrvvh8tyi5jKtZ9bYVBiKzah26bsoEwBPxxIIfUcaPo1p0z03BDfw8IXWw5ve4uGFyNCJranDJKmdQ/KcsykUXA0BVTWws8olZLm6pzIJCwmFhCcJS/WPyqNi@zCqlhxxmqOKU/4ea1CvdesuWdgpJi3UHRYuGvGjGmfcjisExve7yQrOWnEcyyzUubpglhrtYfJhYPigMRow/Cg3m/S/) using an imperative function.

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
<ÆmƤE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/mcFvusSWu/w@3P2paA0Tu//9HR0cbx@pwKShEG@koGBpBmIY6CiY6CsY6ChY6CmZwISOwEFDCFCJkBpSEo1iQGNAsoDKILEgdWMoEzgfZABY1hwoBmWAMUgV1hTFQkSVQHVDYEEQbxMbGAgA)

#### How it works

```
<ÆmƤE  Main link. Argument: A (integer array)

 ÆmƤ   Compute the arithmetic means (Æm) of all prefixes (Ƥ) of A.
<      Perform element-wise comparison. Note that the leftmost comparison always
       yields 0, as n is equal to the arithmetic mean of [n].
    E  Test if all elements of the resulting array are equal, which is true if and
       only if all comparisons yielded 0.
```

Comment: cairdcoinheringaahing's 6-byter (alternative): `ÆmƤµ⁼Ṣ`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Golfed!

Comment: Wow that's brilliant :-)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
a=>a.some(e=>e*++i<(s+=e),s=i=0)
```

Code also works on negative values such as`[-3, -2]`. Returns `false` for a golfy array, `true` for other arrays. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @JustinMariner.

Comment: You can drop the `!` since the spec only asks for two different values, so returning `false` when it's a golfy array is fine.

Answer (score 4):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

```
Max[Accumulate@#-Range@Tr[1^#]#]>0&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zexItoxObk0tzQnsSTVQVk3KDEvPdUhpCjaME45VjnWzkDtf0BRZl6Jg5ZCmoK@g0I1l4JCtXGtjgKINtJRMDSCsg11FEx0FIx1FCx0FMwQYkZgMaCMKVTMDCgNR1AxoAqYMSCVYDkThADIGrCwOUwMyAZjkDqYY4yByiyBKoHihiDaoJar9j8A)

Outputs `False` for golfy arrays and `True` otherwise.

Comment: I see the false/true relationship is reversed but that's OK

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
tYstf/<a
```

Outputs `0` for golfy arrays, `1` otherwise.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L8ksrgkTd8m8b9LyP9o41iuaCMdBUMjIG2oo2Cio2Cso2Cho2AG4RuB@UBRUyDfDCgMR0A@UAakDSQLFjOBcEDGgYXMQXwgDcYgeZBlxkBpS6AKoJghiDaIBQA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `[1, 4, 3, 8, 6]`.

```
t    % Implicit input. Duplicate
     % STACK: [1, 4, 3, 8, 6], [1, 4, 3, 8, 6]
Ys   % Cumulative sum
     % STACK: [1, 4, 3, 8, 6], [1, 5, 8, 16, 22]
t    % Duplicate
     % STACK: [1, 4, 3, 8, 6], [1, 5, 8, 16, 22], [1, 5, 8, 16, 22]
f    % Find: indices of nonzeros. Gives [1, 2, ..., n], where n is input size
     % STACK: [1, 4, 3, 8, 6], [1, 5, 8, 16, 22], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
/    % Divide, element-wise
     % STACK: [1, 4, 3, 8, 6], [1, 2.5, 2.6667, 4, 4.4]
<    % Less than?, element-wise
     % STACK: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
a    % Any: true if and only there is some nonzero. Implicit display
     % STACK: 0
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```hs
and.(z(<=).scanl1(+)<*>z(*)[1..].tail)
z=zipWith
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY6xDsIgEIb3PsWlEygSaWvVpPUJdHJwqAyk1UpEJC0ufXgRiHEygfDfd/9/x02M94tSrocazk7ojqIJVTWmYyu0YmiOq9luQjPcMEo5tUIqnEz1JM1J2pt7CKl9snsm8BDmAMgMUlug0GNompwTaDICLAuCESgI5AQ2BMovyCLweBVA6Ru/w3kC5mWPdtjrNP0/3w8IuZCPoeJbhZ2RrSPwIt7giH/KvWHrPR6y8C45d@/2qkQ/ukVrzAc)

*Edit:* -3 bytes thanks to Zgarb!

**Explanation**

The above point-free version is equivalent to the following program:

```hs
f s = and $ zipWith(<=) (scanl1(+)s) (zipWith(*)[1..](tail s))
```

Given an input `s=[1,4,3,8,6]`, `scanl1(+)s` computes the prefix sums `[1,5,8,16,22]` and `zipWith(*)[1..](tail s)` drops the first element and multiplies all other elements with their index: `[4,6,24,24]`. The list is now *golfy* if pairwise the prefix sums are smaller or equal to the elements times index, which can be checked by zipping both lists with `(<=)` and checking that all results are `True` with `and`.

Comment: You can avoid the type error [like this](https://tio.run/##bY5BDoIwEEX3nGIgLEArsYCoCdxAVy6bLhox2AhjQ@vGePfaNsSVSZv@efP/TO9CP27jaO0AohPYM912uBJxjJ8Mic7bzVsqRouCpxKlSfVV4EizdS64nYRE6KB/RjAJdYZMzRINFDDkwFjFCbCSAC29oARqAhWBA4FmAWUADu88aFzjdziPQL3MxcwnTJL/890An/P5EKqXyu8MbB@AE@F6R/hT5QxH53GQ@nfLuf0C).

Comment: @Zgarb In hindsight this is the obvious solution. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 71 + 18 = 89 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Select((n,i)=>new{n,i}).Skip(1).All(y=>x.Take(y.i).Average()<=y.n)
```

additional 18 bytes for `using System.Linq;`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdFBa4MwGAbgc/MrvmMCWZjWdRtWYQx22mDgYAfxkGWphNq4JWlXEX@7ix5KaUGUhMSQ580XFfZGWNHvrdIlZI11chej8zf2qvRvjETFrYV3U5eG76BFC@u4UwIOtfqGN640ts54lRfATWkJtPCy12KttMsL@lXXVQobSAD1xyQ9skxWUjiMNVUkSbX8a/2sIyzbqh8cEPZUVbgZNn7wrcQNU37pIA0vJSbrpGGa9DF6rrWtK8k@jXLSlynxBvuovGiXHSExXD4TIKQQhFdoAgQUIgpLCg8UVic4DcIReHY3B6x88KnNAT77@gpTYKhkjI/O2TQYPtTI7ueUFPmNYx8OOf2UqTv4/Ed/hDfBMN6OBqFFh7r@Hw)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Generally speaking, import statements are not considered free in code golf. Because this requires the statement `using System.Linq;` it would actually be 89 bytes, sometimes expressed as "71 + 18 = 89" to show that 18 bytes are required but not part of the solution while still having the final count be the last number in the title line (which is helpful for some automatic parsers).

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>62</s> <s>60</s> 62 bytes

- Removed two superfluous parentheses.
- Added two bytes to fix function's reusability (`b=`).

```c
f(A,S,k,b)int*A;{for(S=k=b=0;*A;S+=*A++)b+=!(S<=*A*k++);b=!b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDNasMwEITPzVNsAgXJ3oLttm6DooPzn1x9bHKoXByCiVtCb8bP7q4lV@iQCGTEzjeDtVM8nYqi60qWYY4VKn6uf4NMNOX3leWykkpGguY8lEEWhlyFcszyGQ1BRaNQcqxE210@zzXjzeiB0pB9HEFC84wQtcJIcyMlCHHiyAsjxwgvCOR/R0gdvLQ40ZhMrw5eGZzqkD0a/1zJULLJ4xdICfGhniDQipzfZXMPW3jY0sNWmpnHrm0pbgEbo5rFUr2hZVvL@tq0483BuwGTrL8@7Va@H35I4SnlyRL3d3SzoWh48frGNv9s42FbD9t52L5no7b7Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ηÅA÷W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3PbDrY6Ht4f//x9tpgOFsQA)

Extensive help from Dennis and Adnan got to this reduced version. Also a bug was fixed to make this possible, thanks again you guys. I take little credit for this answer.

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
ηεÅA}ü.S_P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3PZzWw@3OtYe3qMXHB/w/3@0mQ4UxgIA)

---

<s>Long because `DgsO/` is the equivalent of "mean" in 05AB1E.</s>

Apparently `ÅA` is arithmetic mean.

Comment: To compute the means, I'd use `+\÷J` (divide cumulative sum by indices) in Jelly. Is it not that easy in 05AB1E? **Edit:** Nevermind.

Comment: @Dennis ah, cumulative sum in 05AB1E is `ü+` then there's really no divie by indices other than `g` to get array length, `L` to push `1,2,...,n` and divide to get the mean, which is still essentially 5 bytes.

Comment: `.S_` is a LONG way to go for `<=`, if anyone has any ideas lmk.

Comment: Would `÷W` work instead of `ü.S_P`?

Comment: The `ε..}`-wrapper is not necessary as `ÅA` vectorizes automatically

Comment: @Adnan I don't think it does it correctly though.

Comment: @Dennis I'm not sure how that compares consecutive means, that divides by the original input and takes the minimum. Unless you're pointing out a mathematical property that I don't know

Comment: **a ÷ b = 0** if and only if **a < b**. The first quotient is always **1**, so the minimum will by **1** if all a >= b** and **0** if some **a < b**.

Comment: Oh, @Adnan just fixed the vectorization of `ÅA`, so `ηÅA÷W` works now.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

This is an anonymous tacit prefix function (called a monadic train in APL terms).

```apl
∧/⊢≥+\÷⍳∘≢
```

[Try all the test cases on TIO!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHHcv1H3UtetS5VDvm8PZHvZsfdcx41LkIKKlgzJWmYKRgaASkDBVMFIwVLBTMwGwjINtEwRTINoNBINtYAaQSKA7km4BZQM1AnjmIbQpGQAmQocZGCpYKhqYKhkDSAAA)

*Is it*

`∧/` all-true that

`⊢` the elements

`≥` are greater than or equal to

`+\` the cumulative sums

`÷` divided by

`⍳` the integers 1 through

`∘` the

`≢` number of elements

*?*

Comment: APL has a symbol for "the"??

Comment: @user2390246 `∘` binds together things the same way "the" binds together in "count the cats". It is really called *Compose*.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
∧/⊢≥((+/÷≢)¨,\)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHHcv1H3UtetS5VENDW//w9kedizQPrdCJ0QRKKxhzpSkYKRgaASlDBRMFYwULBTMw2wjINlEwBbLNYBDINlYAqQSKA/kmYBZQM5BnDmKbghFQAmSosZGCpYKhqYIhkDQAAA)

**How?**

```apl
            ,\  all prefixes
           ¨    for each
      +/÷≢      calculate arithmetic mean
  ⊢≥            element wise comparison
∧/              logically and the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 60 bytes

```powershell
param($a)$o=1;$a|%{$o*=$_-ge($a[0..$i++]-join'+'|iex)/$i};$o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRUyXf1tBaJbFGtVolX8tWJV43PRUoHG2gp6eSqa0dq5uVn5mnrq1ek5laoamvkllrrZL///9/Bw1DHQUTHQVjHQULHQUzTQA)

Takes input as a literal array (e.g., `@(1, 4, 3, 8, 6)`) into `$a`. Sets our `$o`utput variable to be `1`. Then loops through `$a`. Each iteration, we're (ab)using PowerShell's implicit casting to `*=` the result of a Boolean comparison against our `$o`utput. The Boolean is whether the current value `$_` is `-g`reater-than-or-`e`qual to the previous terms `$a[0..$i++]` added together (`-join'+'|iex`) divided by how many terms we've already seen `$i`. So, if any step along the way is false, then `$o` will get multiplied by `0`. Otherwise, it will remain `1` throughout.

We then simply place `$o` onto the pipeline and output is implicit. `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 27 +2 (-ap) bytes

```
$_=!grep$_*++$n<($s+=$_),@F
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYxvSi1QCVeS1tbJc9GQ6VY21YlXlPHwe3/fzMFCDT9l19QkpmfV/xfN7EAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab and Octave, <s>41</s> 36 bytes

*5 bytes saved thx to Luis Mendo*

```
all([a inf]>=[0 cumsum(a)./find(a)])
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/AAM39974)

Comment: @LuisMendo That would break it if any element of `a` is zero. But that's a handy trick nonetheless in similar situations, have to keep that one in mind.

Comment: Reading is difficult! Thx!

Comment: Happens to me all the time :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 74 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int i=1,s=0;i<x.Count;)if(x[i]<(s+=x[i-1])/i++)return 0;return 1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZJPa4MwGMbvfor3GGnaadt1G9FeCtulg7Eddig9SBrlBZtAEjeH@NldkpXSwy4ajObf73memHAz50qLoTEoK/j4MVacWXTbW@xUXQtuUUmzeBFSaOQsinhdGANvWlW6OEddBK4YW1jk8KXwBK8FSmKsdkKHIxS6MnFY87fSl@dG8myPxmYo7ZaCf0MJ@dDm265UmrgBwDylJk8YZq0L0kjLYixJe8BjRswsd415eozvcDaLtbCNlpCwSyNl/cCubjsXX9Vi8anRij1KQUoixTdcA0AHK@jjeByypJAux2MphTWFFYVHCptJ@DLgTuR@PL6hN8943PlO2LKPGhzXk1j/o4PCwwTcYaF69xGHDJm/lBD27PyfXASnkvpv8r/KuyhOQeQy10f98As)

Returns 0 for false and 1 for true.

3 Bytes longer than core of [chryslovelaces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75118/chryslovelace) [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145706/42502). But in total several Bytes  shorter because my variant doesn't need any `using` statements.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 35 bytes

```
/I?/\+psu0^.\)*sqs;-\;;U;O1.....?@^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/1/f014/RruguNQgTi9GU6u4sNhaN8baOtTa31APBOwd4v7/N1YwAgA)

Not the most efficient use of space (6 no-ops in the code) Produces no output for a golfy array, `1` for a not-golfy array.

Expands to the following cube:

```
      / I ?
      / \ +
      p s u
0 ^ . \ ) * s q s ; - \
; ; U ; O 1 . . . . . ?
@ ^ . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

Explanation forthcoming, but it basically ports something like Luis Mendo's [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145715/67312) or Dennis' [Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145818/67312).

[Watch it run!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgLyBJID8KICAgICAgLyBcICsKICAgICAgcCBzIHUKMCBeIC4gXCApICogcyBxIHMgOyAtIFwKOyA7IFUgOyBPIDEgLiAuIC4gLiAuID8KQCBeIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4K&input=MyAy&speed=5)

Answer (score 2):

## SQL (MySQL), 68 bytes

```
select min(n>=(select ifnull(avg(n),1)from t s where s.i<t.i))from t
```

[Try it online!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91466a/1)

Returns **1** for golfy arrays, and **0** otherwise. Takes input from a [named table](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341), `t`. In order to create `t`, run:

```
CREATE TABLE t(i SERIAL,n INT)
```

and to load the values:

```
truncate table t;insert into t(n)values(3),(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
Λ<mAḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9xsm1zHhzsW////P9pQx0THWMdCxywWAA)

Modification of Mr. Xcoder's solution from the linked repository.

-1, a sweet victory using `all2`!

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 7 bytes

```
ΛΓ·<Aṫ↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///Om86Twrc8QeG5q@KGlP///1sxLDQsMyw4LDZd)

Took me long enough to use `Γ` here.(more than a year!)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 26 bytes

```
[ dup cum-mean v>= vall? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NDoIwEITvPsW8gERA8C/q0XjxYjwZD01dlVhKbQuJGp4dV2pMm8l8nZ3tRUhf2e6w3@42c9zJalIohb9FzgtfOF9IF7ih76SDo0dNWpKDseT909hCe1xJkxWqeHGp0g6LweCNFC1rgjjpTYwxP02R/yhhGiPrKf@fti@GxjfNWYPnRcyTQFl/OQyfpAlmiDPErCO03RHn2kDW5bAkodGslmiEUmucOs61MEY9ETlIRcJ2Hw)

### Explanation

Factor has some pretty great words for this.

```
         ! { 1 4 3 8 6 }
dup      ! { 1 4 3 8 6 } { 1 4 3 8 6 }
cum-mean ! { 1 4 3 8 6 } { 1 2+1/2 2+2/3 4 4+2/5 }
v>=      ! { t t t t t }
vall?    ! t
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda A:all(k*j>=sum(A[:j])for j,k in enumerate(A))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdG7DoIwFAbg3ac4YQLTGLmISlITFkcnN@xQY4lcS1oYfHpsS6JoRJo2Hfr1P700j/bOa69P8aUvaXW9UYgjWpZ2scwPWHaVHSdRTpyUC8hRAVkNrO4qJmjL7NhxeiolEy2kduIT@GoOYAxn0bHFW3kIXI/MKRdBgMBHsEMQkj/KM0rZzaQKVcSrTyqV8nmsQR1pKcdMVzJJAZlh@qIGb8k0U8tm6EDzfj@Zr7L2Kk5JV89rMmKNyOoWrBOHYUPG1RcJwYVcWf0T)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>50</s> <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

- Saved two bytes by inlining and using `and`.
- Saved two bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) by chaining assignment `S=k=0`.
- Saved two bytes by using `or` and the comparison's boolean value as `k`'s increment value.
- Saved two bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs); raising a `NameError` by using an undefined variable instead of a `ZeroDivisionError`.

```python
S=k=0
for j in input():k+=S<=j*k or J;S+=j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xbsIwEIbn@Cl@eWqLVZGEUprWUwRIHeiQblGHCBmRhMaRY1R4@vRsEkA6y7r/@87n9mz3uon6VHLO@0zWcsp22qBC2VC1R/vwmNQTmX3I6qkGkc/3bCKrnnRmzTlh@NuXB4U0YcEaEt/mqFjgCNRJbZGyQJ22qrXYFL9qaYw2CZy4Kg4dmUXXKWPHVZASazYMLL9Wg9@asrHgG42LXuoGyqHumfd5/MP81jwSCKOxCQVmArHAQmB@F0Y@JPQyhnMSrjWG5NBTl0/mzvZ4dh@5dR683lLq/HFufI1jUt/IJhK6ezqQfw)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7NTsMwEITP8VOMcgIaQX5KC6nMJbS9wSGciHqIilGdVHFku9A@fVinSam0lrUz3@xue7I71cRdxn3f73Je85B9K40KsqFqD/bmNs1fqrsaZfOF8CFc1BMeLfIJrzqKMKtPKcPvTu4FspR5a3B86INgnnMgjmKLjHniuBWtxafQ6lX@SCNVs9Ra6RQusCr3hhKlMULbcS04x5oNweX7auBbLRsL/03hjNMkCGeZe78rkg3rtxdxgCgemyjANEAS4CnA7EqMe5Gsx1GcEXCpUSSGRp2PLBzd29Nrya3rjfm/Sl3/HJtc5ITQZ6LJidwfDs4f) for your alternative version.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks.

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY6xbsIwEIbn@Cl@eWqLVZGEUkjrKQI2OoQt6hAhVyShceoYFZ4@PZuEIp1l3f9953N7sQfdRH0qOed9Jms5ZV/aoELZULUn@/CY1BOZvcvqqQaRn7dsIquedGbNJWH4PZRHhTRhwQYSO3NSLHAE6qz2SFmgznvVWmyLb7UyRpsETlwXx47MouuUseMqSIkNGwZWH@vBb03ZWPCtxlUvdQPlUPfM@zz@ZH5rHgmE0diEAjOBWGAhML8LIx8SehnDOQm3GkNy6KnrJ3Nnezy7j9w6D17/U@r8cW58i2NSl2QTCd09Hcgf)

Comment: @ovs Thanks; neat one-byte way to raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
->a{0until a.pop*a.size<a.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1LDsIwDET3nMKCHQoV/fCToDuWcIEqi7QNUAmSKm0WUHr2YhsEworl8ZtJ4nx@H067YZaqbu5NW11BBbWtpypoqofe4vC3fsiyWArIIgFhRCIUkAiIBawFLD8gYoB4QWCJxvcQQI@vUoBp8tnoUWYrBii4KcGfxhjYYAZhSHMuZaBVcYHSwlM9R4CV63NlWFHVrjItjCed6mGXwvhn@LaBU6YkE6ebwms42oNuL7bcO2cd5fV//r1qU46whxc)

Inspired by [Lynn's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145705/73819). Throws `NoMethodError` for golfy, returns `nil` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [q/kdb+](http://kx.com/download/), 14 bytes

**Solution:**

```
min x>=avgs x:
```

**Examples:**

```
q)min x>=avgs x:1 4 3 8 6
1b                           / truthy
q)min x>=avgs x:4 2 1 5 7
0b                           / falsey
```

**Explanation:**

Fairly simple with the `avgs` built-in:

```
min x>=avgs x: / solution
            x: / store input in variable x
       avgs    / calculate running averages
    x>=        / array comparison, x greater than running average
min            / take minimum of list of booleans
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 29 bytes

```julia
!x=any(find(x).*x.<cumsum(x))
```

Returns *false* or *true*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5hC4JADIa/@yumINzFlO7OLKGi/1F@kEy4yCs04fr11@4UYWPb875se04v3ZTOxfbUmB/rtGmZ5fnG5sf71I9TTxN33XsAC9oAiwCuqkZfJIKQcysQCgSFcEAoVyQDImE3o5LENWZE@rLC24JSrLM/EOh@QdSG9K7lCUWminyEha/bOuLEL59Bm2/HkjQT1QjZGdLxZhIEixBbHj1M6/4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 54 bytes

```
D,g,@@#,BFB
D,k,@,¦+AbL/
D,f,@,dbLR$€g€k0b]$+ABcB]£>ª!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZA7CsJAEIbr3VOsMZ0DmsT3i7hIqlRiJykSY4JvUbQRG68iWIinyFG8SJxZUYkIOyzzf/PPLr8fhptNmvYhBtvOg3Qk78McbEiuhV7gFrGLsAsDd6A/zvcYa14KPL3Qk2PpJZducsuhe7aermhBEzjTRLvTFdqMo3fpo07ayPK0A2OsJYbb/YQEE4RhKvGrGSDKICwQdRBVYhlkKoQDlSyq4vDnZBHOv99w/MVOabRAzZb/EPqV4rXXoi9DTRUZrR9ooa2BTuQG3aUMl17IGQZ3jE7YqNiOFNiJc50CSp8)

#### Unoriginal version, 30 bytes

```
D,f,@,¬+AbLRBcB/@0@B]ABcB]£>ª!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQefQGm3HJJ8gp2QnfQcDB6dYRyAr9tBiu0OrFIEqsvIz83QcHJStdLg4lRRsbO0UlLK4uFx0chOB4iCxaONYpTJOTk5rhZCi0lSQgJGOgqERWBAhZqijYKKjYKyjYKGjYAaSQ5EyAksBFZiiSpkBFcMRqhRQPcwOt8ScYrAYyACwWhMsMiBXgeXNIQYh5IBiYAzSaIwmaQzUZgnUCZQ3BNEGKPJOsSlcnI@a1lSn1QI54GCrBgVYLReXCiiA/gMA)

Both output **1** for golfy arrays and **0** otherwise

### How they work

The first version was created by me, without checking any other solutions. The second was inspired by Dennis' [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145699/am-i-a-golfy-array/145762#comment356541_145719), so I'm less happy with it.

#### The first version

Here, we define our main function \$f\$ that computes the *golfiness* of our input array, \$A\$. First, we need to yield the suffixes of \$A\$, which is done by first generating the range \$B := [1, ... \vert{A}\vert]\$, where \$\vert{A}\vert\$ denotes the length of \$A\$. This is done with the code `dbLR$`, which leaves \$[B, A]\$ as the stack. We then iterate the dyadic function \$g\$ over these two lists. Being dyadic, the function binds its left argument as \$A\$ for each iterated element. It then iterates over the range \$B\$, which each element from \$B\$ being the right argument provided to \$g\$. \$g\$ is defined as

```
D,g,@@#,BFB
```

which is a dyadic function (i.e. takes \$2\$ arguments), and pushes its arguments to the stack in reversed order (`#`) before execution. `BF` then flattens the two arguments. We'll assume that the arguments are \$A\$ and \$e \in x\$. This leaves the stack as \$[...A, e]\$, where \$...\$ represents an [array splat](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Finally, `B` takes the first \$e\$ elements of \$A\$ and returns a list containing those elements.

*Note* : The function names \$g\$ and \$k\$ aren't chosen randomly. If the commands given to an operator (such as `€`) doesn't currently have a function (which [`g` and `k` don't](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus/blob/master/add%2B%2B.py#L1082)), then the named functions are searched for a matching function. This saves \$2\$ bytes, as normally the function would have to wrapped in `{...}` to be recognised as a user-defined function. At the time of writing, the currently unused single byte commands are `I`, `K`, `U`, `Y`, `Z`, `g`, `k`, `l`, `u` and `w`.

When \$g\$ is applied over the elements of a range \$x\$, this returns a list of prefixes for \$A\$. We then map our second helper function \$k\$ over each of these prefixes. \$k\$ is defined as

```
D,k,@,¦+AbL/
```

which is the standard implementation of the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean). `¦+` calculates the sum of the argument, `AbL` calculates its length, then `/` divides the sum by the length. This calculates the arithmetic mean of each prefix, yielding a new array, \$C\$.

Unfortunately, \$C\$ contains the mean of \$A\$ as its final element, and does not include the mean of the empty list, \$0\$. Therefore, we would have to remove the final element, and prepend a \$0\$, but popping can be skipped, saving two bytes, for reasons explained in a second. Instead, we push \$[0]\$ underneath \$C\$ with `0b]$`, then concatenate the two arrays forming a new array, \$C^+\$.

Now, we need to check each element as being less than its corresponding element in \$A\$. We push \$A\$ once again and zip the two arrays together with `ABcB]`. This is the reason we don't need to pop the final element: `Bc` is implemented with Python's [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function, which truncates the longer arrays to fit the length of the shortest array. Here, this removes the final element of \$C^+\$ when creating the pairs.

Finally, we [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) \$p \in A, q \in C^+; p < q \equiv \neg(p \ge q)\$ over each pair \$p, q\$ to obtain an array of all \$0\$s if the array is golfy, and array containing at least a single \$1\$ if otherwise. We then check that all elements are falsey i.e. are equal to \$0\$ with `ª!` and return that value.

#### The second version

This takes advantage of Dennis' approach to remove \$24\$ bytes, by eliminating the helper functions. Given our input array of \$A\$, we first compute the cumulative sums with `¬+`, i.e the array created from \$[A_0, A_0+A_1, A_0+A_1+A_2, ..., A_0+...+A_i]\$. We then generate Jelly's equivalent of `J` (*indicies*), by calculating the range \$B := [1 ... \vert{A}\vert]\$ where \$\vert{A}\vert\$ once again means the length of the array.

Next, we divide each element in \$A\$ by the corresponding index in \$B\$ with `BcB/` and prepend \$0\$ with `@0@B]`. This results in a new array, \$C^+\$, defined as

$$C^+ := [0, A_0, \frac{A_0+A_1}{2}, \frac{A_0+A_1+A_2}{3}, ..., \frac{A_0+...+A_i}{i+1}]$$

The final part is identical to the first version: we push and zip \$A\$ with \$C^+\$, then starmap inequality over each pair before asserting that all elements in the resulting array were falsy.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> 34 bytes

```r
function(x)any(cumsum(x)/seq(x)>x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7bCsIwDIbvfYpdJvCD9jTdhb7LKBYGW512he3pawQvxC4JCcmX06uEawk5@mV4RFq5jxv5PKU8SXJM96eE28ol9fM8bjQOaSGDQ/MjnjSU5v@igoXBBe0O0UIsXEVafLUiBvUF2SC9dqcuDwk718ThYzJk6gsaHZSDEn9iRhO4vAE)

Comment: very nice. Dunno why there wasn't an R answer before...

Comment: You were all saving an easy one for me.

Comment: instead of defining `y` in the function arguments, using `cumsum(x)` directly is 4 bytes shorter. It's a shame `cummean` doesn't exist in base R.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
Kvṁ<≈
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJLduG5gTziiYgiLCIiLCJbMSwgNCwgMywgOCwgNl0iXQ==)

Porting jelly got me feeling like yeet.

### Explained

```
Kvṁ<≈
K     # prefixes of the input
 vṁ   # the mean of each of those prefixes
   <  # is the input less than each of those means? 
    ≈ # and is everything the same?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 55 bytes

```
f(l)=\sum_{n=2}^{l.\length}\{l[1...n-1].\mean>l[n],0\}
```

Outputs `0` for golfy array, and a positive integer otherwise.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qpyjlv6fxf)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nctchn5mvi)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 109 bytes

Golfed version, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHPS8MwFIDv@yseOyWjlLWdU6sZ6E3QXcTTEHnWtIukqSTZQUr/9voShpeNNeQn@fK9l8RVqHHsPr9l5eEFlYF@/JI11AzLZ@X87sn4d14@dp2WaESP0KKv9n2FTsJWabHx9iDv4vJDbDB1h/ZeMEy1NI3fL2iCzi@YqhkpU2WU5zwDqYlfcj4MI0CI11JohrZxJTxYi7@7V2@VaSg0vNEZENDPgAo6J60nV0iOFZyDEBBS4Ge28wSy/DKSJbBKoEjgJoH1JJpHlA5cXUbXJPuvl1HyHVOskR7lHBLiRdVqGgxXjvj1FEtMbMFbTMAFaW/JTHwWxuUJH7sf@jKvDZtvu6NAdQaktZ116TyAw2wY/wA)

```scala
def f(a:List[Int]):Boolean={a match{case Nil=>true;case _=>a.sum<=(a.length*a.last*(if(f(a.init))1 else 0))}}
```

Ungolfed version

```scala
object Main {
  def f(a: List[Int]): Boolean = {
    a match {
      case Nil => true
      case _ => a.sum <= (a.length * a.last * (if(f(a.init)) 1 else 0))
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    assert(f(List(3)) == true)
    assert(f(List(2, 12)) == true)
    assert(f(List(1, 4, 3, 8, 6)) == true)
    assert(f(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) == true)
    assert(f(List(6, 6, 6, 6, 6)) == true)
    assert(f(List(3, 2)) == false)
    assert(f(List(4, 5, 6, 4)) == false)
    assert(f(List(4, 2, 1, 5, 7)) == false)
    assert(f(List(45, 45, 46, 43)) == false)
    assert(f(List(32, 9, 15, 19, 10)) == false)
    
    println("No assertion errors.")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>11</strike> 10 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder

```
.A.egb.O<Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X89RLzU9Sc/fJvD//2gTHQUIMjQyjgUA)

Comment: 7 bytes: `SI.OM._` (port of cairdcoinheringaahing's solution from Jelly, by Erik the Outgolfer), or 10 bytes using your approach: `.A.egb.O<Q`

Comment: Post the port as yourself, it's a totally different approach!

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 96 bytes

I know it's not a good golfing language, but I still gave it a go!

Input array as first argument of comma separated ints to test.

Returns 1 for true, 0 for false.

```java
a->{int i=1,j,r=1,s=0;for(;i<a.length;i++,s=0){for(j=0;j<i;s+=a[j++]);r=s/i>a[i]?0:r;}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZAxb4MwEIVn8ytOmUAkhK51SOcOjSp1RAzXxHFMwKCzSRUhfjs9o0Ttcvb53nv@dDXecNP1ytan63xs0Dn4QGPHKBLGekVnPCo4jBGI0IOOuZYVJjISE2v64bsxR3AePR@3zpygZXv85clYXVaAyRgJsd3CJ5JTDvxFwdmQ84Ckh1Zxpu8gRCMR3uHcESh0dxgcasXWvyTSDgrAMq8y1zfGx6v1KnCIBenhL8Cqn5BXBn3WKKv9pQoqTg7wYFiTSzC7fwJu03QhFUtMaSpWvfMCtKKsD@jcxMHBo4yR2jhZ/p4C4t151Wbd4LOeYX1sMx0vOclzT48FHcBy7oyb/bigFC/rek1cXZHLACgZ68nESOE9GcOgZkG9M9KlBZZ1mlaJpMJtzR4Z6C1/JTmR8gNZ4NssZDTNvw)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 100 bytes

Golfed:

```
int g(int[]a){int i=1,m=0,s=m,r=1;for(;i<a.length;){s+=a[i-1];m=s/i;r-=a[i++]<m&&r>0?1:0;}return r;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int golfy(int[]a)
{
    int i = 1, m = 0, s = m, r = 1;
    for (; i < a.length;)
    {
        s += a[i-1];
        m = s / i;
        r -= a[i++] < m && r>0? 1 : 0;
    }
    return r;
}
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/PKbP0K)

Returns 0 for ungolfy and 1 for golfy arrays. Slightly longer than java 8 answer.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 44 bytes

```php
while($n=$argv[++$i])$n<($s+=$n)/$i&&die(1);
```

takes input from command line arguments, exits with `0` (ok) for a golfy array, with `1` else.

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/97b667fd199426672be0ecd47a98b93c848d4366).

Answer (score 0):

## J, 19 bytes

```
[:*/[>:[:}:0,+/\%#\
```

`+/\ % #\` averages of the prefixes: `#\` produces 1..n

`}:0,` add 0 to the beginning and remove the last

`[>:` is the original list element by element >= to the shifted list of averages?

`*/` are *all* the elements greater, ie, the previous list is all `1`s?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEX3@YqDIkUtNkmbqgP1R9qdGKQbF1332@NgERLmAffMnZk5xYVBsGilUU7N@JBRVrH1uZkO@ykdze5CFQepqFmFuBhjXs/3B8dApM2Fx/lcOzpabvQl9Ao7Qg77f2zQbrfxudQVdXRASfWrTq4FDL9Ud1sc9NxxAafdpi8)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 39 bytes

```
{for(;i++*$i>=s&&i<=NF;s+=$i);$0=i>NF}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYu7DsIwDEV3f8UdogrIkmehCu7Ysf/AgmQxIJGhA@LbUwOxravjI93b9mjtfX@@DpWFXRFrT0ZmrsMgV16XUi0bORbjWOZ1@fjWIvpQgA9/8kiIuGBUCkoJmUb0pYjQG@rVpB9pW78zpYzvqY4UAyb4DK/paAc)

Note that the TIO link has 5 extra bytes `i=s=0` to allow for multi-line input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

Came up with two 10 byte solutions, can't seem to improve on that.

```
eÈ¨U¯Y x÷Y
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ZcioVa9ZIHj3WQ==&input=WzMyLDksMTUsMTksMTBd)

---

### Explanation

```
               :Implicit input of array U
eÈ             :Is every element, at 0-based index Y
  ¨            :Greater than or equal to
   U¯Y         :U sliced from index 0 to index Y
        ÷Y     :Divide each element by Y
       x       :Reduce by addition
```

---

### Alternative

```
eÈ*°Y¨(T±X
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ZcgqsFmoKFSxWA==&input=WzMyLDksMTUsMTksMTBd)

```
               :Implicit input of array U
eÈ             :Is every element X (at 0-based index Y)
  *°Y          :Multiplied by Y incremented by 1
     ¨         :Greater than or equal to
      (T±X     :T (initially 0) incremented by X
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 51 bytes

```
foldIndexed(0,{i,s,e->if(s<0||s>e*i)-1 else s+e})>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFPT8MgGIfv/RRvSA@gbGm7P@qyNZkHTZMdTObBK11pRRGWQpct3T77pJ1NNHElEA7vw/P@gE9tpVDnvFKwEsbOE2XjYYHJ4pxrmSUq43ue4YDWghrKB7HIsZkHx6OJ@Y0ggxC4NBzMLT@ROGg1zBhe2sQ8a5kfMN9v@cbybAaPWkvOFIUdK1lZQDoD14xA7YEbOyaBbWzltgWkQ6ubNJg0Udr6thTKSoWRX4sccIcuoGtAAO3gZbleo0sk9AZPy2SFTlBgv06HH1qoV722zlNgRBE5ERAG/IuJgnnXlcwg5eB3SkS8k@c1d/piQmEX2sxgWZbsML944i793zvbsuIURuRqKaIQRtfLIYWxO0/hnsK0F4tazMGT69j09/wPy5l7r1YU9ZSbJq1j3A9FbTCH3vVxk5/V@EZ9oZzuwRkdGzZ7QDz3J@dv)

(69 bytes with entire declaration of extension function)

```
fun List<Int>.g()=foldIndexed(0,{i,s,e->if(s<0||s>e*i)-1 else s+e})>0
```

Comment: This should be enclosed in a lambda

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 33 bytes

```
$=>[0v:0some?&'x['v+x x<v//<=1+]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?QwRpvR)

Returns `false` for true and `true` for false.

```
$=>[             ; a function, assign input to &
    0            ; push 0 to the stack, this represents the current count of elements
    v:0          ; assign 0 to v, this represents the running average
    some?&'x[    ; is there any x in the input that...
        'v+x     ; add x to v in place
        1+       ; add 1 to value on top of the stack
        <=       ; duplicate top of stack
        x<v//    ; is x less than v divided by top of stack?
    ]            ; end some?
]                ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƒ€m<ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

Port of Dennis's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
ƒ€m<ạ  # Implicit input
ƒ      # Prefixes of the input
 €m    # Mean of each prefix
   <   # Input is less than this?
    ạ  # All equal (all are 0?)
       # Implicit output
```